# How to take into consideration the input values between integers when plotting graphs?

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib, visualization

### My Code

---

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

xmin, xmax=-3,3
x= np.array(range(xmin, xmax+1))
y,ysqr,ycube = x,x**2,x**3

f, (ax1, ax2, ax3) = plt.subplots(1,3, figsize=(25,8))

ax1.plot(x, y)
ax1.set_title('y=x')

ax2.plot(x, ysqr)
ax2.set_title('y=x^2')

ax3.plot(x, ycube)
ax3.set_title('y=x^3')

plt.show()
```

### Problem

---

But the graphs are not smooth because only integers are considered.
[image]

### What I want

---

How to take into consideration the values of x between integers when plotting graphs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [`numpy.linspace`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.linspace.html).

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

xmin, xmax=-3,3

x = np.linspace(xmin, xmax, num=1000)
y,ysqr,ycube = x,x**2,x**3

f, (ax1, ax2, ax3) = plt.subplots(1,3, figsize=(25,8))

ax1.plot(x, y)
ax1.set_title('y=x')

ax2.plot(x, ysqr)
ax2.set_title('y=x^2')

ax3.plot(x, ycube)
ax3.set_title('y=x^3')

plt.show()
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: what is the `num=1000` doing? can you please tell...

Comment: @DronBhattacharya, Yes, this function split numbers between -3 until 3 to 1000 nums. you can run this simple example: `print(np.linspace(start = 0, stop = 1, num=5))` output is `[0.   0.25 0.5  0.75 1.  ]` for your problem because you want to plot a more accurate plot, we can generate `1000` num and then plot these 1000 nums between `[-3,3]`. Or in short, we split [-3,3] into 1000 parts. you can reduce or increase this parameter base on a different problem.